# Sequelize does not execute in AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js

I´m having trouble executing a sequelize statement using lambda. The lambda executes without any errors, however no instance is added to my table in the DB. I have tried running the code locally not using lambda, which works just fine. I have logged the event values as well, they are correct. Seems like a connection can not be established.

The database is not secured behind VPC and running on AWS as well.

```
var config = require('./config.json');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var connection = new Sequelize(config.dbname, config.dbuser, config.dbpassword, {host: config.dbhost, dialect :'mysql'});

var BuisnessUsers = con.define('BuisnessUsers', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    CVR: Sequelize.STRING,
    adress: Sequelize.STRING,
    zipcode: Sequelize.STRING,
    phone: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    contact: Sequelize.STRING,
});


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    connection.sync().then( async function(){
        const ost = await BuisnessUsers.create({
            name: event.name,
            CVR: event.CVR,
            address: event.address,
            zipcode: event.zipcode,
            phone: event.phone,
            email: event.email,
            contact: event.contact
        });
    });
    callback (null, null);
    
};
```

EDIT:
Solved: Callback returned before the connection was done